# GeneratedValue for a Big Int setting a digit size JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have an entity:

```
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id",
            nullable = false)
    private Long id;
```

id in my database is a big int column.

I need the generated value to be 6 digits, nothing less, nothing more.

In my service class I am formatting it properly with

`String.format("%06d", transfer.getId());`

It works mostly, although there are times when the GeneratedValue exceeds 6 digits and it causes a logic error in my program.

Is there a way to enforce it within JPA to generate ids of 6 digits? (Or perhaps in the database, directly?)

I have thought about using the Random util class to generate a random value, but there is a chance the same random value would be generated again and be persisted to the database causing an issue there.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a char(6) column in your database?

Comment: Our client's contract specifies that it must be an integer related column unfortunately :(

Comment: Okay, but why save six fixed digits in database if you are using a sequence? Can't you save the numeric value in database and use the formatted value in your application?

Comment: The problem is its generating values that are longer than 6 digits, and the format line: String.format("%06d", transfer.getId()); isn't getting the first 6 digits.

Comment: But now it's a database problem isn't? The generator create a +1 sequence value and the database id column has reached the six digits number? In this case I don't know what to do besides change the digits format number.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding this annotation:

```
@Size(max = 6)
```